# How to use geom_rect when having a date variable as x axis [R]?

Tags: r, date, time

I have a database with a variable with dates (data$time) and numeric values (data$ert). I'm new to R, trying to learn (checked a lot of links here, on Google; used ?geom_rect too), probably it's a silly question.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    data<-read.csv("pt1.csv", header=T, sep="\t", dec=",")
    data$time<-as.Date(data$time, "%d/%m/%y", origin="1970-01-01")
    pt1.plot<-<-ggplot(data, aes(time, ert, group=1, na.rm=T))+geom_rect(aes(xmin=2, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="lightgreen", alpha=0.03)+geom_line()+labs(x="", y="ert")+geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.5), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed")
    pt1.plot
```

When trying to visualize the plot it gives me this error:

```
    Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

I can not understand how to supply the origin info into geom_rect.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the min and max parameters from the `aes` call your plot should render correctly. Here's an example with some toy data:

```
# Create made up data
data <- data.frame(time = seq(1, 10, by = 1),
                   ert = runif(n = 10))

# Turn into date format - added as.Date to origin statement
data$time<-as.Date(data$time, "%d/%m/%y", origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"))

# Verify similar structure to OPs dataset
head(data)
#         time       ert
# 1 1970-01-02 0.4485163
# 2 1970-01-03 0.8100644
# 3 1970-01-04 0.8123895
# 4 1970-01-05 0.7943423
# 5 1970-01-06 0.4398317
# 6 1970-01-07 0.7544752

pt1.plot<- ggplot(data, aes(time, ert, group=1, na.rm=T))+
  geom_rect(xmin=2,
                xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill="lightgreen", alpha=0.03) +
  geom_line()+
  labs(x="", y="ert")+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.5), colour="#990000", linetype="dashed")

pt1.plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is there a way to calculate the number that correspond to a certain date? Otherwise I will have to try numbers and go with a visual control of the plot.

Comment: you could try `as.numeric(as.Date("yourdate", "%d/%m/%y", origin = as.Date("1970-01-01")))`

Comment: also, if this answers your question, please accept the answer to close the question!